# Localize storyboard programatically on the fly

Tags: ios, swift

My app allows user to change country, so if they change to Thailand, I am supposed to update my storyboard etc's language. 
P/S: I've seen a lot of people say if you relaunch the app you'll be fine, but that's really a user experience issue I wanted to prevent.
The following is my current attempt, it works fine for programatically created/modified/defined text but it doesn't update the text on my storyboard :(

```
import UIKit
class LocalizationHelper: NSObject {
    static var bundle: NSBundle?
    static let sharedInstance = LocalizationHelper()

    func localizedStringForKey(key: String, comment: String) -> String {
        return (LocalizationHelper.bundle?.localizedStringForKey(key, value: comment, table: nil))!
    }

    func setLanguage(language: String) {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(language, forKey: "LocalizedStringUserDefaultsKey")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(language, ofType: "lproj") {

            print(language)
            print(language)

            LocalizationHelper.bundle = NSBundle(path: path)
            print(LocalizationHelper.bundle)
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Base", forKey: "LocalizedStringUserDefaultsKey")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
            LocalizationHelper.bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        }
    }

}
```

The print statement result is

```
Optional(NSBundle </var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/91776A02-BADA-4EC9-A451-45A453B84C83/Appname.app/th.lproj> (not yet loaded))
```

Does this matter anything? 
For the record, I referenced this

> https://github.com/jslim89/JSLocalizedString

P/S: I have also have my Main.string(Thai) in my Main.storyboard(Base) ready, just that they only update when I change System Language :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have outlets defined for each UI component in storyboard. You can simply localize them by calling `NSLocalizedString`:

```
self.title = NSLocalizedString("MyTitle", nil);
```

The other option could be to have multiple storyboard one for each supported language. Once user change the country, based on the supported language pick the right storyboard. Something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard_English", bundle: nil)
```

Comment: Sorry, I only have 1 storyboard, also, that means I need to create every outlet(including text in my tab bar controller items and update them on every viewwillappear. Hence I'm avoiding that too